# Which automation engine to use as desiredCapability in appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android

The below list is from the official website but the problem I ran through is if I use UiAutomator1 in my desired capability everything works well and if I select UiAutomator2 it start giving JAVA_HOME path issue. Would it be fine if I continue with UiAutomator1? As I am not sure about the difference they have except the performance

Appium (default), or UiAutomator2, Espresso, or UiAutomator1 for Android, or XCUITest or Instruments for iOS, or YouiEngine for an application built with You.